# Privacy Policy for an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iOS app and I need to show links for Privacy Policy and Terms of use.

What is the recommended way to show it? Opening links in Safari on a button click or in a WebView inside the app?

As it is a policy from Apple that any app that is making Users Log into the app, should provide how the data will be used and terms of use. So basically it is a mandatory feature to add.

Comment: Can you edit why the app needs to show these? If it's an Apple policy, we can surely help you interpret that policy. If it's just because you want it - then this is pretty much off topic for here since it's about making an app. As long as it it about using the Apple Developer services - we can reopen this once it's clarified.

Comment: Also Abhinav - since someone already edited this for grammar - your edit won't get reviewed for a reopen - so please @ ping me in the comments to flag for review once you've added what you want.

Comment: @bmike , As it is a policy from Apple that any app that is making Users Log into the app, should provide how the data will be used and terms of use. So basically it is a mandatory feature to add.

Comment: So you're referring to the metadata portion of app submission - when you upload to the App Store you have to have a URL where your privacy policy is? What I'm trying to get you to do is edit in a reference to Apple policy at Developer.apple.com so that the body of the question has all the information needed to answer once all the comments here are deleted.

Comment: [App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage) states:  `(i) Privacy Policies: All apps must include a link to their privacy policy in the App Store Connect metadata field and within the app in an easily accessible manner.` 

The review guidelines doesn't explicitly mention the way the policy should be presented, but emphasises that it be available for easy access to the users of the app. So it implementation detail is totally up to the developers choosing as long as the privacy policy is accessible by the users.